# Pixelization of KDE screen

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, kde, video, nvidia

I am using Arch Linux on an [Acer Aspire 5920G](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/Aspire5920G/Aspire5920Gsp2.shtml) and *KDE 4.6.5* as WM. All installed packages are up-to-date.

Starting some days ago I got few strange artifacts that spread all over the screen. Interestingly they do not affect any open window at all (neither QT nor GTK or a regular X window). Only the three buttons at the top (maximize, minimize, close) are pixelized but the "content" of any window is intact.

When starting a "good-old X session" instead of KDE there is not artifact at all.

This is a current screenshot. Note that all of the KDE *widgets* (don't know how they are called) are pixelized while they "eyes" and the whole background image are not at all. Fullscreen apps (games) and Windows work perfect as well.
[image: My KDE desktop]

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

This is a part of the X log:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i nvidia
[    22.675] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    22.708] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  275.19  Tue Jul 12 18:31:51 PDT 2011
[    22.764] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    22.797] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    22.910] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    22.991] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  275.19  Tue Jul 12 18:15:26 PDT 2011
[    22.991] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    23.097] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    23.134] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    23.134] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    23.134] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    23.134] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    23.134] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinView" "0"
[    23.134] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "1280x800 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
[    23.134] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
[    24.334] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (AUO (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    24.334] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    24.354] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 8600M GT (G84) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 60.84.41.00.18
[    24.354] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce 8600M GT at PCI:1:0:0
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0):     AUO (DFP-0)
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): AUO (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.354] (--) NVIDIA(0): AUO (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link LVDS
[    24.391] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: DFP-0
[    24.391] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    24.391] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "1280x800+0+0"
[    24.391] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select+0+0"
[    24.391] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1280 x 800
[    25.419] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (98, 96); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    25.420] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    25.420] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    25.433] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1280x800+0+0"
[    25.864] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    25.864] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    25.864] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    25.867] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    25.868] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   402.168] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1280x800+0+0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the closed source driver. Maybe it has a bug.

You could try to switch to an open source driver: Change in `Section "Device"` the Driver line to `Driver "nv"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

At least this is where the configuration is stored in my Debian. You can search for a line like this in your log file:

```
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
```